# Vue.js, Visual Studio 2015 and .less styles syntax highlighting

Tags: visual-studio-2015, less, vue.js

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and vue.js to implement frontend for my web app.

As it known, vue.js comes with quite special approach to declare components - each component should be declared in a single `.vue` file, that contains all required code (template, script and style) and looks like this:

```
<template>
    <!-- Component template goes here. -->
</template>

<script>
    <!-- Component code goes here. -->
</script>

<style>
    <!-- Component style goes here. -->
</style>
```

There is no official support for .vue files in MSVS at the moment, so I just use HTML editor to edit that files and it works fine for me.

So, back to the problem...

Vue-files allows you to set required language for script or style (just add `lang` attribute to `script` or `style` tags and here you go). So, as I am using less, my style tag looks like this:

```
<style lang="less">...</style>
```

Visual Studio, of course, know nothing about special lang attribute, so I add some well-known attributes in order to enable less syntax highlighting and now style tag looks like this:

```
<style lang="less" rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/less">...</style>
```

Unfortunately Visual Studio don't understand my intention to use less and highlight my less code like simple css :-(

**So, my question is:** how to let Visual Studio understand .less styles, that embedded right into html document?

---

*P.S. It is allowed to reference separate files for any part of .vue component like this...*

```
<template src="./template.html"></template>
<style src="./style.css"></style>
<script src="./script.js"></script>
```

*...but I really want to store everything inside single file.*

*And, of course, I want to use single IDE for both frontend and backend, so advice like "just use Visual Studio Code, SublimeText or WebStorm" is not very useful.*

Comment: Having the same issue!

Comment: Hi, I understand you so much, but, after all, I decided to use WebStorm for my frontend projects. First I was frustrated that WebStorm has similar problems, but, at least, it was solvable - here is my question about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35333641/how-to-enable-syntax-highlighting-for-embedded-less-styles-in-webstorm. Please, read question and answer carefully and you will be happy with single-file .vue components :-) More of that - WebStorm has better JS support with all that new ES6 features and so on - I strongly reccomend it if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a vue.js pack for visual studio which provides the IntelliSense for the Visual Studio 2015.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.VuejsPack

Comment: This would be the solution, but the lack of support for ES6 in vue.js pack makes this extension unusable for me

Comment: This extension does not solve the inline style lang='less' problem